# c#: How to Show Success Message in Client Before Page Redirects to Another Page

Tags: c#

What I want to do is when user clicks a `submit` button, the backend code will add it into database, and show a success message in client before the page is redirect to the next page. How do I write code in backend? I use

```
this.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "clientScipt", "<script>alert('Done!');</script>");
```

But the message never shows, it just jumps into next page directly.

Help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered using AJAX?

Comment: Is AJAX the only way to do that? I remember this could be done by pure server side code, just forgot how to do it. Besides, I have too many parameters if using AJAX.

Comment: Are you calling `RegisterClientScriptBlock` in the `Page_Load` or in the button handler?

Comment: You're trying to do two things on one action when mentally you want one result on each of actions. First, when the operation succeeds, show the user a success message (you've done that part). Then, after they click OK, redirect. It sounds like you're redirecting from the server. Use a client side redirect after the alert: `window.location.href="default.aspx"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the few apps where this has been requested, we have a "Success.aspx" page.  The page simply shows a success message, and then does a timed redirect to the next page.  Usually, we pass along the redirect target as a POST variable.

The timed redirect is handled by Javascript similar  to this:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
<!--
setTimeout("location.href = 'http://whateverpage.aspx;",1500);
-->
</script>
```

We do it via javascript (client-side) because you can do a redirect in server-side code, but not with a delay.  The Redirect is immediate and the "Success" message is never displayed.

I do feel compelled to add, however, that these "Success" pages are somethign we stopped doing unless the user explicitly asks for it because they become very annoying after a while.  They seem like a good idea at the time, but provide a very poor suer experience.    You might be better served just putting a "Success" message next to the buton and using the same setTimeout function to then set the display of that "Success" to "none" so that it disappears after a few seconds.

Comment: This previous post shows a cleaner implementation of the suggested approach in the end paragraph of my answer.  If you use it, go vote that guy up!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202015/how-to-show-success-message-on-submit

Comment: I also need to redirect page, so that approach does not match my requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the message in the Session, and have your master page output/clear the session variable you used so the message only gets displayed once.  You would be displaying the message on the redirected page instead of the original page.  If you really need to display the message on the original page, you will have to use ajax.

Here's an extension method I use for adding messages to the session (includes a css class parameter so we can color the error based on messaage type):

```
    public const string Index = "messages-some-unique-key";

    public static void AddMessage(this HttpSessionStateBase session, string message, string messageClass)
    {
        if (session[Index] == null)
            session[Index] = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

        var list = (IList<KeyValuePair<string, string>>) session[Index];
        list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(
                     message, messageClass));
    }
```

Pulling the messages out is just looping through that object, then setting session[Index] to null.  I happen to use an IDisposable and an MVC2 HtmlHelper to display my messages, so I don't think my code for displaying likely would be useful to your particular situation.

Here's some code you *might* use to convert the messages to html (not null safe):

```
public static string GetAndClearMessages() {
var list = (IList<KeyValuePair<string, string>>) Session[Index];
var listTag = new TagBuilder("ul");
var tags = new StringBuilder();
foreach(var kvp in list)
    {

        var liTag = new TagBuilder("li");
        liTag.AddCssClass(kvp.Value);
        liTag.SetInnerText(kvp.Key.ToString());
        tags.AppendLine(liTag.ToString());
        listTag.InnerHtml = tags.ToString();

    }
    Session[Index] = null;
    return listTag.ToString();
}
```

It is worth noting that this is a better practice than showing a success message then redirecting because it doesn't slow your users down.  You only want to do that for *very important* messages, not reporting success; the expected condiiton.

Comment: What part, retrieving the message, or putting the code to display the message on every page on the site (or at least the ones you redirect to).