# Button click is reloading an empty page

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

my problem is that whenever I click on a button an empty page reloads after calling the button on click event.
The page includes the following code only

```
    <html>
      <head></head>
      <body>2015</body>
    </html>
```

What I want to do is either display a message that the form has been submitted or redirect to a different page. `Response.Direct` and `Server.Transfer` didn't work and I tired to wrap the form in a panel and create a different panel that is set to visible after the form is submitted like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202015/how-to-show-success-message-on-submit) example but that didn't solve the issue every time I click the button the page reloads as the code above. I can't use `OnClientclick="return false;"` since I want my onClick event to be called. Here's some of my form's code (the button's ID is `btnSumbitSurvey`):

```
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <div id="wrapper">
          <div id="page-wrapper">
            <div class="wrapper-content" runat="server" >
              <div runat="server" id="SelectLang">                   
                <asp:Label ID="lblLanguage" runat="server" CssClass="select-lang" style="text-align: center;" Text="Select Survey Language | اختر لغة الاستبيان"></asp:Label>
                <asp:RadioButtonList  ID="rblLanguage" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlSelectedIndexChanged"  runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" >
                </asp:RadioButtonList>
              </div>
            <div ID="details" class="survey-details" runat="server" Visible="False">
               <span runat="server" class="name" ID="SurveyName"></span>
               <p runat="server" class="desc" ID="SurveyDescription"></p>
               <div runat="server" id="questionsList" >
                 <asp:Repeater ID="rptQuestionsEng" runat="server" Visible="False" OnItemDataBound="rpt_ItemDataBound" >                                
                    <ItemTemplate>
                      <div class="question">
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hide" Value='<%# Bind("QuestionId") %>' runat="server" />
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblQuestion" Text='<%# Bind("QuestionEng") %>' CssClass="questionLabel"></asp:Label>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvEng" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="rblQuestionEng" ForeColor="red" ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>      
                        <asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="rblQuestionEng">                           
                        </asp:RadioButtonList>      
                      </div>
                   </ItemTemplate>
                  </asp:Repeater>
                 </div>
                 <asp:Button ID="btnSumbitSurvey" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmitSurvey_Click" Visible="False" class="btn"/>
                 </div>
                </div>
               </div>
              </div>
            </form>
```

Code behind:

```
     protected void btnSubmitSurvey_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
       if (rblLanguage.SelectedValue.Equals("1"))
         {
            List<Response> responsesList = new List<Response>();
            foreach (RepeaterItem item in rptQuestionsEng.Items)
            {
                Response response = new Response();

                if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
                {
                    var rbl = (RadioButtonList)item.FindControl("rblQuestionEng");

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(rbl.SelectedValue))
                    {
                        answerId = Convert.ToInt32(rbl.SelectedValue);
                        response.QuestionResponse = rbl.SelectedItem.Text;
                        response.ResponseDate = DateTime.Now;
                        response.SurveyId = _surveyId;
                        response.PateintSurveyId = _patientSurveyId;
                    }                        
                }
                var hide = item.FindControl("hide") as HiddenField;
                var id = hide.Value;
                int questionId = Convert.ToInt32(id);

                response.QuestionAnswerId = _blSurvey.GetQuestionAnswer(questionId, answerId);
                responsesList.Add(response);                   
            }

        if (_blResponse.AddResponse(responsesList))
        {
            Response.Redirect(Enums.ReferenceLinks.PostSubmission + "?E=F", true);
            //postPanel.Visible = true;
            //prePanel.Visible = false;
            //SubmitMsg.InnerHtml = "Thank you for participating, your submission has been received";
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: you didn't say which button is causing the redirect, and didn't show the code-behind, which is the most important part

Comment: @FabioLuz Okay sorry, I will update the question

Comment: Is your condition rblLanguage.SelectedValue.Equals("1") is TRUE?  and _blResponse.AddResponse(responsesList) returns true?

Comment: @KaiserNayan Yes I'm sure I debugged the code. The issue occurs after the last statement of the click event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent hours trying to figure out were the problem was. Eventually, I deleted all the javascript codes in my pages, specifically the ones I had in the footer and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have checked IsPostBack like -

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    // load defaults, language list, repeater etc.
}
```

I guess you did not use it therefore every time you post the form it loads defaults settings and condition is not meeting.

Comment: I did use it, and inside it I gave default values to my dropdownlist and sat the visibility of some of the controls.